# xslt merge sub nodes to one root node

Tags: xslt, merge, nodes

My input document consist of a root with several sub nodes.
...

```
<root>
    <top>
        <number>999</number>
        <attr attr-name="Numbervalue">
            <value>184</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Initials">
            <value>A.C.</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Givenname">
            <value>Anne</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Surname">
            <value>Bakker</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Function">
            <value>Developer</value>
        </attr>
    </top>
    <top>
        <number>999</number>
        <attr attr-name="Numbervalue">
            <value>1034</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Initials">
            <value>A.C.</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Givenname">
            <value>Anne</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Surname">
            <value>Bakker</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Function">
            <value>Consultant</value>
        </attr>
    </top>
</root>
```

...

I want to merge all subnodes from top into a merged top. Same attributes but different values should result in a multi-valued "value" node. Other nodes/fields (as "number") should be copied. Something like this:
...

```
<root>
    <top>
        <number>999</number>
        <attr attr-name="Numbervalue">
            <value>184</value>
            <value>1034</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Initials">
            <value>A.C.</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Givenname">
            <value>Anne</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Surname">
            <value>Bakker</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Function">
            <value>Developer</value>
            <value>Consultant</value>
        </attr>
    </top>
</root>
```

...

What i have tried:
...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="top">
        <xsl:for-each select="./attr[@attr-name]">
            <xsl:if test="string-length(.)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="name" select="./@attr-name"/>
            <xsl:variable name="value" select="normalize-space(./value)"/>
            <attr>
                <xsl:attribute name="attr-name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </value>
            </attr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...

But this result in:
...

```
<root>
  <attr attr-name="Numbervalue">
    <value>184</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Initials">
    <value>A.C.</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Givenname">
    <value>Anne</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Surname">
    <value>Bakker</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Function">
    <value>Developer</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Numbervalue">
    <value>1034</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Initials">
    <value>A.C.</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Givenname">
    <value>Anne</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Surname">
    <value>Bakker</value>
  </attr>
  <attr attr-name="Function">
    <value>Consultant</value>
  </attr>
</root>
```

...

With this i am missing the top node and nodes like "number"
If the result looks like this (below) it is also acceptable:
...

```
<root>
    <top>
        <number>999</number>
        <attr attr-name="Numbervalue">
            <value>184</value>
            <value>1034</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Initials">
            <value>A.C.</value>
            <value>A.C.</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Givenname">
            <value>Anne</value>
            <value>Anne</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Surname">
            <value>Bakker</value>
            <value>Bakker</value>
        </attr>
        <attr attr-name="Function">
            <value>Developer</value>
            <value>Consultant</value>
        </attr>
    </top>
</root>
```

...

I am also experimenting with "Muenchian Grouping" but up till now this only results in errors.
A working solution should use only xslt 1.0.

Suggestion are very welcome!

Comment: Can it be assumed that each `top` has the same `attr`s, only with (possibly) different `value`s?

Comment: @michael.hor257k i already commented your solution. It works. One issue (maybe) is that most of the time the attr's are the same but there is no absolute garantee.

Comment: Well, then you will need to start by grouping all `atttr`s by `attr-name`, and only then do the secondary grouping of `value`s.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k Will try if i manage to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="value" use="../@attr-name" />
<xsl:key name="k2" match="value" use="concat(., '|', ../@attr-name)" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <top>
            <xsl:copy-of select="top[1]/number"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="top[1]/attr">
                <attr attr-name="{@attr-name}">
                    <!-- get only distinct values of this attr -->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', @attr-name)[count(. | key('k2', concat(., '|', ../@attr-name))[1]) = 1]"/>
                </attr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </top>  
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This takes the list of `attr` elements from the 1st `top`, gathers all the `value` elements that belong to the current  `attr` (using the `k1` key), and filters them using the Muenchian grouping expression (utilizing the `k2` key) to output only the distinct values among them.

Comment: Thank you very much @michael.hor257k ! Quick test seems its working. Nice!